# Plowshare with disabled JS interpreter

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I try to use plowshare to download files with command line but on ubuntu I got this error: "Use of Javascript interpreter is disabled in debian for security."

I've found that I should add environmental variable: "PLOWSHARE_DEBIAN_JS=yes"
I added it to ".bashrc" in home directory, with source after that but it doesn't work, i can't find anything what can help, anyone know how can i enable JS?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a resolve. But I fixed this issue by command `export PLOWSHARE_DEBIAN_JS=yes` then you might encounter another issue like "Javascript interpreter not found. Please install one" just install nodejs `sudo apt-get install nodejs`